# "fertilizers" or "fertilizer"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> xxx company also makes fertilizer to help feed the world’s growing population.

Though the operation may produce a wide range of fertilizers, why the singular form of fertilizer is used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fertilizer isn't a single thing. Right? A bag of fertilizer has a lot little tiny bits of stuff in it. Whether it's a bag, a truckload, a warehouse, or whatever, i.e., however much, it's still called fertilizer.

Fertilizers refers to different types ... of fertilizers, not of fertilizer. Okay, it really is types of fertilizer. The problem is that it's one word that is used in two different ways.

One sense is a specific thing: bag of fertilizer refers to the specific contents of the bag. The other sense is a type of thing: there may be multiple types of fertilizer in the bag. But you wouldn't say you bought a bag of fertilizers.

In the context of making something to help feed the world, there is no more distinction between the fertilizers than there is in a bag of fertilizer.

Fertilizers would be used: xxx company also makes fertilizers to accommodate a variety of crops.